# Select icon from scroll view

Tags: ios5, uiscrollview, icons

I want the user to select an icon in an iOs app. The number of possible icons is bigger than what can be shown on one screen. What is the best way to do this?
I am thinking about using a scroll view and creating custom buttons on it that have the icon as the background image... Does anybody know some other way? Also a scroll view tutorial for this would be useful...
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely thinking right. `UIScrollView` is definitely the way to go. And custom buttons are how I normally do it as well for simplicity.

Here is an excellent tutorial for exactly what you're trying to do :) Couldn't write it simpler myself so might as well just link it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker